# Magento 2.3 extreamly slow with over 100 cart lines

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am working in a Magento 2.3 installation with avarage cart size of 100-150 lines.
Getting the visible cart items from Quote is slower over time ( as products count rises )

I've search thought Magento core and i've found that the delay is caused when it tries to get the Quote from the database (?)

in  **$quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($this->getQuoteId());**

```
public function getQuote()
{
    $this->_eventManager->dispatch('custom_quote_process', ['checkout_session' => $this]);

    if ($this->_quote === null) {
        $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create();
        if ($this->getQuoteId()) {
            try {
                if ($this->_loadInactive) {
                    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($this->getQuoteId());
                } else {
                    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($this->getQuoteId());
                }

                /**
                 * If current currency code of quote is not equal current currency code of store,
                 * need recalculate totals of quote. It is possible if customer use currency switcher or
                 * store switcher.
                 */
                if ($quote->getQuoteCurrencyCode() != $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode()) {
                    $quote->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore());
                    $this->quoteRepository->save($quote->collectTotals());
                    /*
                     * We mast to create new quote object, because collectTotals()
                     * can to create links with other objects.
                     */
                    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($this->getQuoteId());
                }
            } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                $this->setQuoteId(null);
            }
        }

        if (!$this->getQuoteId()) {
            if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn() || $this->_customer) {
                $customerId = $this->_customer
                    ? $this->_customer->getId()
                    : $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId();
                try {
                    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActiveForCustomer($customerId);
                    $this->setQuoteId($quote->getId());
                } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                }
            } else {
                $quote->setIsCheckoutCart(true);
                $this->_eventManager->dispatch('checkout_quote_init', ['quote' => $quote]);
            }
        }

        if ($this->_customer) {
            $quote->setCustomer($this->_customer);
        } elseif ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $quote->setCustomer($this->customerRepository->getById($this->_customerSession->getCustomerId()));
        }

        $quote->setStore($this->_storeManager->getStore());
        $this->_quote = $quote;
    }

    if (!$this->isQuoteMasked() && !$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn() && $this->getQuoteId()) {
        $quoteId = $this->getQuoteId();
        /** @var $quoteIdMask \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteIdMask */
        $quoteIdMask = $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load($quoteId, 'quote_id');
        if ($quoteIdMask->getMaskedId() === null) {
            $quoteIdMask->setQuoteId($quoteId)->save();
        }
        $this->setIsQuoteMasked(true);
    }

    $remoteAddress = $this->_remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();
    if ($remoteAddress) {
        $this->_quote->setRemoteIp($remoteAddress);
        $xForwardIp = $this->request->getServer('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
        $this->_quote->setXForwardedFor($xForwardIp);
    }

    return $this->_quote;
}
```

The delay is on average about 15-25 seconds. Is there a way to store this kind of data in a caching storage like Redis ? I've already set Redis as a storage cache with no luck.

Is anyone else experiencing this kind of issue? Magento Changelog claims that carts should be fine when containing about 300 lines

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.0CE.html

The project runs on a dedicated server with 32gb of RAM and 8 Cores XEON Cpu

**UPDATE**

After some more investigation i've found that the delay is on Quote.php line 1380-1391

```
public function getItemsCollection($useCache = false)
{
    if ($this->hasItemsCollection()) {
        return $this->getData('items_collection');
    }
    if (null === $this->_items) {
        $this->_items = $this->_quoteItemCollectionFactory->create();
        $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor->process($this->_items);
        $this->_items->setQuote($this);
    }
    return $this->_items;
}
```

The weird thing is that there isn't any traffic on Redis CLI monitor when requesting this collection, shouldn't this kind of data be stored in Redis?

**UPDATE 2**

There seems to be a "plugin" or something around getItemsCollection function. I've stopped execution in it and the response was immediate, if i let it returns the $this->items is shows the delay. Tried to use xdebug in order to find what causes the delay with no luck. Xdebug followed execution until Collection.php where i lost track. Mysql profiler showed around 1500 queries running in cart page ( i think this is a huge number ) although none of them lasted longer than ~5ms ( there where some around 15ms ).

So i've installed a fresh magento installation with luna theme and imported the sample products using composer. 
The new vm has MySql 5.7, PHP-FPM 7.2 and redis.
Enabled production mode, all caches except page_cache and set the deafult cache to redis
Added 46 items in cart and the result for just the Document load was ~13s

[image]

I can't accept that Magento can't handle this kind of cart size. This time is not acceptable from the end-users.

No clue from where to start searching.

Comment: I would start by looking at what goes on the `quoteRepository->getActive` and then checking the database has useful indexes set on sensible columns

Comment: @RiggsFolly  I've never altered database indexes in any way. Is the delay is from the database shouldn't be a slow query entry in the logs?

Comment: Depends if you have Slow Query Logging turned on

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ok I've meant that it is on and there aren't any logs written